# Simple probability confusion

Tags: probability

I have confused myself by the following argument I would love some help with.

Let $f(a,b)$ be a function that equals $1$ or $0$. Let $a \in \{1,\dots, n^4\}$ and $b \in \{1,\dots n\}$ be independent uniform random variables.  Let us say we know that $P_{a,b}(f(a,b) = 1) = p$ when $a$ and $b$ are chosen uniformly at random.  I would like to argue that therefore there exists an $i$ for which $P_{b}(f(a,b)= 1|a=i) \leq p$ when $b$ is chosen uniformly at random.

Is this correct or is there a similar statement one can make that is true?

Comment: I think your notation is somewhat confusing. Is $b$ a random variable taking values in $\lbrace 1,\dots n\rbrace$? Is $P_{a}(f(a,b) = 1)$ then the same as the conditional probability$ P(f(a, b) = 1 | b = i) $?

Comment: @user126540 Sorry for the confusion. I have attempted to fix it. You are basically right except I had the wrong subscript. $a$ and $b$ are both random variables  as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say $f(a, b) = 1$ when $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ where $A \subset \lbrace 1, \dots n^4 \rbrace$ and $B \subset \lbrace a, \dots n \rbrace$. Then $$P(f(a, b) = 1) = P(a \in A, b \in B) = P(a \in A)P(b \in B)$$ assuming $a$ and $b$ are independent. In the same manner $$ P(f(a, b) = 1 | a= i)= \begin{cases}0 & i \not\in A \\P(b \in B)& i \in A \end{cases} $$  So basically, the inequality holds every time $a \not\in i$ but false when $a \in A$ since
$$
p = P(a \in A)P( b \in B) \leq P(b \in B | a= i)= P(b \in B)  = P(f(a, b) = 1|a=i). 
$$ 
Conclusion: your hypotheis is true.
Acknowledgement: I was hung over while doing this, so it might not be waterproof.